# Else-If With Same Condition

Tags: if-statement, language-agnostic, logic

```
if (Condition1)
{
    dothis;
}
else if (Condition1)
{
    dothat;
}
```

Out of curiosity, when I invoke the same condition for the `else if`, will the `dothat` part of the code still execute when `Condition1` is satisfied? Does this vary from programming language to programming language?

Answer (score 9):

What you wrote is basically equivalent to

```
if(Condition1)
{
  dothis;
}
else
{
  if(Condition1)
  {
    dothat;
  }
}
```

So no, it will never be called.

Answer (score 8):

No, the second condition will never be executed in any language. [Here is a basic flowchart of your logic](http://www.doctormckay.com/screenshots/2014-03-17_1637.png).

However, if `Condition1` somehow evaluates to `false` in the first condition and `true` in the second, then the second will be called. Example:

```
<?php
$var = true;
function condition() {
    global $var;
    $var = !$var;
    return $var;
}

if(condition()) {
    echo "Conditional 1";
} elseif(condition()) {
    echo "Conditional 2";
}
```

In this case, "Conditional 2" will be printed because `condition()` first evaluates to false, and then to true.

Answer (score 1):

While *at most one branch is executed<sup>1</sup> per if-else-statement*, in cases where the "condition" contains a a side-effect, it might not always be the `if` branch that is executed.

For instance, consider [this JavaScript code](http://jsfiddle.net/x58Av/) *with* a side-effect introduced by the "condition" expression.

```
y = -1;
if (++y) {         // the "condition" is ++y
  alert("1")
} else if (++y) {
  alert("2")
}
```

Only one branch ("2") was executed, but the *same* "condition" was used in both cases. For such reasons it can be problematic to have side-effects in conditionals.

---

<sup>1</sup> In all modern mainstream languages the conditions for an if-else are evaluated "on demand" and "in order". Thus the first branch for which the condition evaluates to true is executed, regardless of other side-effects, and it is the *only* branch executed.

Comment: Some people keep a cattle prod around for resolving cases like this.  :)

Comment: @cHao Or a shotgun loaded with rock salt ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The second `if` follows an `else` – consequently, it will only be executed if the first `if` does *not* succeed. So – no; the `dothat` will not be executed. All (sane) programming languages do this.

However, some programming languages have special constructs for an `else if`, and you have to write it as one statement, variously called `elif`, `elsif` or `ElseIf`, depending on the language.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Condition1` evaluated to `True` the `if`'s "dothis" will be invoked and skip over the `else if`. If you wanted to invoke the `dothis` and `dothat` then you would have two `if` statements with the same `Condition1` or just put both `dothis` and `dothat` under one `if` statement. This is what I have seen in computer programming languages I have used.

Python example.

```
b = 2
if b == 2:
    print "Hello"
elif b == 2:
    print "World"
... 
Hello
```